# How to convert an Amazon S3 bucket excel file to CSV file and store it in the same bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have excel file in my Amazon s3 bucket and I want to convert that excel file into a CSV file and store it into same bucket I know we can do that with AWS GLUE DATABREW but I want to do by python coding so please provide me good reference. Also, if you are providing AWS LAMDA function trigger method than please share me reference of how set trigger for an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: For best results, show the code you've tried and note where you get stuck. If you don't know where to start: `boto3` to read/write the file from s3, a python module to parse .xslx contents, and google for tutorials on how to use these components

Answer (score 1):

This use case can be solved writing a Lambda function. If you write this in Python, then use the AWS SDK for Python from within a Lambda function. Use the [Python S3 API](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/python/example_code/s3) to read the Excel file.

You can retrieve the excel data using a [Python Excel API](https://www.python-excel.org/). AFter you use Python code to convert the Excel data into CSV data, place the data into a CSV file and use the Python Amazon S3 API to write the CSV file back into the Amazon S3 bucket.

If you do not know how to write a Lambda function using Python, see:

[Building Lambda functions with Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html)

If you do not know how to invoke a Lambda function when an object is placed into an Amazon S3 bucket, see:

[Using an Amazon S3 trigger to invoke a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)